# How to split string with awk using '\t|' sting as a separator?

Tags: linux, awk

I am trying to split the string using custom field separator like this:

```
$ echo -e "abc\t|def" | awk -F '\t|' '{print $1, $2}'
abc |def
```

I expect output to be:

```
abc def
```

But instead it also includes `|` character which is part of separator:

```
abc |def
```

If using `'\t#'` as a separator I am getting expected output:

```
$ echo -e "abc\t#def" | awk -F '\t#' '{print $1, $2}'
abc def
```

So by some reason `|` character in field separator does not work as expected.
How can I make it work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```
awk -F '\t[|]' '{print $1, $2}'
```

`-F` will get evaluated as a regex. Put the `|` into a character class since it has special meaning in the regex.

Alternatively you can use:

```
awk -F '\t\\|' '{print $1, $2}'
```

Comment: Forgot that field separator is a regex.